# SQL Server 2008 does not show the Management Studio option

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a new database using SQL Server 2008, and these are the steps that I follow:

`Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 ->`

I get 2 options:

1. Configuration tools
2. Import and Export Data (32 bit).

So I choose `Configuration tools` and then get these options:

1. SQL Server Configuration Manager
2. SQL Server error and usage reporting
3. SQL Server Installation Center

When I click `1. SQL Server Configuration Manager` and start `SQL Server sqlExpress` I get an error stating request failed or server did not respond in timely fashion.

Could you guys please help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you don't see the Mgmt Studio option you forgot to select to install it during your SQL installation.

Comment: I guess ms sql server got installed when i installed visual studio web developer 2010

Comment: In that case it is 100% definitely not an option to install with VS.

Answer (score 0):

You need SQL Server with Tools download.  When you install with that package you will have the ability to install Management Studio.

You can get it here: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you installed SQL Server Express alongside with Visual Studio, you're not getting Management Studio. You need to:

- either download and install [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365247.aspx) from the Microsoft web site
- use Visual Studio as your frontend to SQL Server Express (works for most tasks - but not all)
- install a full version of SQL Server and make sure to choose the `Client Tools` feature (that's the Management Studio) and use that to administer your `.\SQLExpress` instance